# Efficiently handle unknown controller action in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, task-parallel-library

My site is facing unwanted robot call to a specific MVC controller with varying action name. It causes huge exception for hitting into nonsexist action. Our logging system almost flooded with error.

We have decided to adopt following approach as a work around.

1. Efficiently handle request for non-exist action so it doesn't throw exception
2. Throttle down robot call

We have written below code to achieve this. Can any one please review the approach.

```
protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
{
   if (this.ActionInvoker.InvokeAction(this.ControllerContext, 
      "ReturnErrorForUnknownAction")) return;
}

public ActionResult ReturnErrorForUnknownAction()
{
   return Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(t =>
   {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }).Result;
}
```

Above code is working fine but not sure if "**ReturnErrorForUnknownAction**" is a blocking call. As per my knowledge **Task.Result** blocks current thread.

My original intention is to implement Asynchronous delay before sending 404 status.

Answer (score 0):

using `Task.Result` can cause locks. change the method to something like...

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ReturnErrorForUnknownAction()
{
   return await Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(t =>
   {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried above code , but it throws an error

"**Additional information: The asynchronous action method 'ReturnErrorForUnknownAction' returns a Task, which cannot be executed synchronously.**"

Error comes form method **this.ActionInvoker.InvokeAction**